# Know if Client is Busy in ZK

Tags: zk, zul

Is there any way to know if at client side Busy box(Processing Label) is being shown (any method like `isBusy()).`

Further can I do `clearBusy()` on an Event. Like click on an `Button`.

Note:if you can answer first part pls do post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some low level JS API in ZK for the first question i.e. to check if a busy message is being shown.

For the second part you can use do it by calling Clients.clearBusy(Component) Note: you should be calling Clients.showBusy(Component, String) for this to work

```
<zk>
<window border="normal" title="hello">
    <div height="200px" width="200px" style="background:yellow">
        <button id="btn1" label="Show Busy" onClick='Clients.showBusy(self.getParent(), "Busy")'/>
    </div>
    <div height="200px" width="200px" style="background:red">
        <button id="btn2" label="Clear busy" onClick="Clients.clearBusy(btn1.getParent())"/>
    </div>
</window>
</zk>
```

See the live demo [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1fpg9pg/1-showBusy-and-clearBusy-example)

Comment: zAu.processing() gives me the client state at client side but how do I get it at server side is again an problem, I donnot want to send the push from client to server to make server know that busy is shown at client side.

Comment: Can you explain what use case you have that requires such a check? Normally Clients.showBusy(String) and Clients.clearBusy() are used together for processing long operations. For eg. you use Clients.showBusy() before starting an asynchronous operation and use Clients.clearBusy() after the long operation is over.